# merge multiple file using common IDS

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing

I have many files, which I want to merge using common Ids in Column 1.

File1:

```
MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1   Atypical/PIKK/FRAP
MYORGANISM_I_06518.t1   CAMK/MLCK
MYORGANISM_I_00854.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/SH2-R
MYORGANISM_I_12755.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/Unique
```

File2:

```
MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1   VALUES to be taken
MYORGANISM_I_12766.t1   what
```

FILE3:

```
MYORGANISM_I_16941.t1   OK
MYORGANISM_I_93484.t1   LET IT BE
```

I want to  merge many file and add '-NA-' if value is missing, my desired Output:

```
MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1   Atypical/PIKK/FRAP  VALUES to be taken  -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_06518.t1   CAMK/MLCK   -NA-    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_00854.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/SH2-R  -NA-    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12755.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/Unique -NA-    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12766.t1   -NA-    what    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_16941.t1   -NA-    -NA-    OK
MYORGANISM_I_93484.t1   -NA-    -NA-    LET IT BE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not possible using a single tool. Here is a script-based suggestion that involves a call to `sort`, and two temporary external files.

```
#!/bin/bash

# The number of columns is equal to the number of input files, which is
# equal to the number of command-line arguments.
NUMCOLS=$#


# Use associative container to record all "IDs" and associated fields
declare -A entries
col=0


# Read the fields from all files and store them so that the field values can be
# associated with the file they came from (= the column they belong).
for FILE in "$@"
do
    while read id value
    do
        SORTKEY="$id"__"$col"
        entries[$SORTKEY]="$value"
        echo "$id" >> "tmp.ids"
    done < $FILE
    let col=$col+1
done

# Sort the IDs
sort -u "tmp.ids" > "tmp.ids.sorted"


# Read the sorted IDs back in and generate output lines, where the
# column fields are taken from the associative container "entries" and
# tab-separated.
# If "entries" doesn't contain a value for a given key, output "-NA-" instead.

while read id
do
    LINE="$id"
    for (( col=0; col<NUMCOLS; col++ ))
    do
        SORTKEY="$id"__"$col"
        if [[ -z "${entries[$SORTKEY]}" ]]
        then
            LINE=$(printf "%s\t-NA-" "$LINE")
        else
            LINE=$(printf "%s\t%s" "$LINE" "${entries[$SORTKEY]}")
        fi
    done
    echo "$LINE" >> "outfile.txt"
done < "tmp.ids.sorted"

rm tmp.ids tmp.ids.sorted
```

You would call this as `./sortscript.sh <file1> <file2> ... <fileN>`.

This would generate an associative container `entries` and store all fields read from your input files under a key generated from the "ID" field and the column number. The IDs are written into an external file `tmp.ids` so that they can be sorted, which seems to be what you want.

After sorting, the IDs are read back in. Then, for each ID, all available fields belonging to that key are read from the container `entries` and placed on on an output line (the variable `LINE`). If no value is available for a specific ID/column combination, write `-NA-` instead.

The output lines are then written to a file `outfile.txt`.

Comment: sorry, I am not able to understand this code. For the trial purpose, I have taken two files and change the script `NUMCOLS=$#` to `NUMCOLS=$2` . But it is not working, do I need to change `col=0` to `col=2`.

Comment: Actually, all you should need to do is copy the code and paste it into a file called `sortscript.sh`. All internal variables are automatically set, you only have to call the script as indicated in my answer. Could you elaborate in what way the code doesn't work for you?

Comment: After changing your script as described in my earlier comment, I wrote the command `bash merging.sh /media/anjali/anjali_10TB/result_annotation_with_id_1 /media/anjali/anjali_10TB/interproscan-5.38/final_with_id` error: `merging.sh: line 49: tmp.keys.sorted: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'tmp.keys': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'tmp.keys.sorted': No such file or directory`

Comment: I see. As I wrote, you don't need to change the script. The `$#` variable is an internal bash variable and automatically contains the number of command-line arguments, which is the number of files you called the script with. Please try it again without changes. As for the error messages that is a typo on my side. Please replace "tmp.keys" and "tmp.keys.sorted" with "tmp.ids" and "tmp.ids.sorted".

Answer (score 0):

One liner to be executed in shell (/bin/sh or /bin/bash):

```
FILES="File1 File2 FILE3"; LIST=$(for F in ${FILES}; do cat ${F}|awk '{print $1}'; done|sort|uniq|xargs); for i in ${LIST}; do echo -n "$i"; for F in ${FILES}; do L=$(grep "^${i}\s" ${F}|head -1|sed 's/\t/ /'|cut -d' ' -f 2-|sed 's/^\s*//g'); [ -z "${L}" ] && echo -n " -NA-" || echo -n " ${L}" ; done; echo; done|sort
```

Output:

```
MYORGANISM_I_00854.t1 TK-assoc/SH2/SH2-R -NA- -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1 Atypical/PIKK/FRAP VALUES to be taken -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_06518.t1 CAMK/MLCK -NA- -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12755.t1 TK-assoc/SH2/Unique -NA- -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12766.t1 -NA- what -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_16941.t1 -NA- -NA- OK
MYORGANISM_I_93484.t1 -NA- -NA- LET IT BE
```

Explanation:

```
# create list of files
# it can be created based on search like
# find . -type f -name filename.txt
# or something different
FILES="File1 File2 FILE3";
# create a list if unique first lines from all files from the list FILES
LIST=$(for F in ${FILES}; do cat ${F}|awk '{print $1}'; done|sort|uniq|xargs);
# take one by one each first line
# and go through all the files find corresponding lines endings
# and put them together
# or take '-NA-' for non-existing
for i in ${LIST}; do
    echo -n "$i";
    for F in ${FILES}; do
        #
        # old version of line commented out
        # L=$(grep "^${i}\s" ${F}|head -1|cut -d' ' -f 2-|sed 's/^\s*//g');
        # new version of line to make tab separator working
        L=$(grep "^${i}\s" ${F}|head -1|sed 's/\t/ /'|cut -d' ' -f 2-|sed 's/^\s*//g');
        #
        [ -z "${L}" ] && echo -n " -NA-" || echo -n " ${L}" ;
    done;
    echo;
done|sort
# sorted results printed
```

Comment: It is working but creating two columns of IDs and 3rd column with first file and 4th column again IDs then File2 and File3.

Comment: 1) What do you mean saying "column"? There are 2 part of each line: "key " and "the rest", because if we count columns, the line "MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1 Atypical/PIKK/FRAP VALUES to be taken -NA-" has 7 columns? There is nothing specified about "columns" in the task.

Comment: 2) I created your 3 files and executed the one line command specified above. I printed my output. Is your output different? Can you provide with more details?

Comment: It is working on these sample FILES but with my original file, it is not working. May be because my files are having tab delimiter.

Comment: I edited both: a) the single line command, 2) version with explanation. The code added is "|sed 's/\t/ /'", it should make files with tab separator working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `join` utility twice to produce two "outer joins" on the three files. Assuming all three files are tab-delimited, first the two first files:

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e '-NA-' -t $'\t' <( sort File1 ) <( sort File2 )
MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1   Atypical/PIKK/FRAP      VALUES to be taken
MYORGANISM_I_06518.t1   CAMK/MLCK       -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_00854.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/SH2-R      -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12755.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/Unique     -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12766.t1   -NA-    what
```

This asks the `join` utility to join the sorted files on the first field (which is the default). We explicitly say `-a 1 -a2` to get all lines from both files, even if they don't match, and with `-o 0,1.2,2.2` we request the output to consist of the join field (the first column) along with the second column of each file.  The `-e '-NA-'` option specifies what string to fill empty fields with.

The above gives us a new dataset that we could use in a second join with the third file.  For simplicity, assume that the above result is available in `tmpdata` (after having been redirected there), then

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 -e '-NA-' -t $'\t' tmpdata <( sort FILE3 )
MYORGANISM_I_00854.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/SH2-R      -NA-    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_05140.t1   Atypical/PIKK/FRAP      VALUES to be taken      -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_06518.t1   CAMK/MLCK       -NA-    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12755.t1   TK-assoc/SH2/Unique     -NA-    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_12766.t1   -NA-    what    -NA-
MYORGANISM_I_16941.t1   -NA-    -NA-    OK
MYORGANISM_I_93484.t1   -NA-    -NA-    LET IT BE
```

This repeats more or less the same "outer join" from before, but also adds an extra column with  the `-o` option.